# What action is removing a shield and dropping it to the ground?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions

I know that removing an equipped shield **and stowing** it (usually on the back) is a standard action.

I also know that dropping an held or wielded item is a free action.

What action type is removing an equipped shield and let it drop to the ground?

Comment: As reference I'd add that this is (also) listen in PHB p 289 - although your q isn't answered there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, it is a standard action to remove your shield from your arm. From the *Rules Compendium* pg 267:

> **Using a Shield**
>
> To use a shield, a creature must strap it to the forearm. Doing so is a standard action, unless otherwise noted. **Removing a shield is also a standard action.**

If you choose to remove and stow it on your backpack, that is described specifically on pg 245 (*Equip or Stow a Shield* ) as also being a standard action.

It appears the hard part is unstrapping it from your arm. Putting it someplace once it's off is the easy part.

Comment: So, stowing it on your backpack is a sort of gift: you already spent a standard action to remove the shield, I (the rules) allow you to stow it without additional effort. :) I this yours is the most realistic interpretation of the cross-reference you quoted.

Comment: Oh, and as always... _Blessed be the Rules Compendium!_

Comment: _Blessed_ in the sense _Oh man we screwed up these rules so bad, let's put out the errata as a supplement and not dare reprint PH1, which would piss off our existing fanbase and fuel flames that Essentials is 4.5e_.

Comment: Yes! That kind of blessing. :) Irony apart, I think they have made a good work, and messing up is somewhat intrinsic in handling the huge amount of material that has been published. Anyway, I'm not going to open a topic on this argument: it's not the correct place for this kind of discussion. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that your shield is actually strapped to your arm. Therefore to drop it you first have to unstrap it.

Unstrapping it and stowing it is a standard. I would probably require the same for dropping it. I feel like the reason for making equipping and unequipping a shield a standard is to make it difficult and I think that downgrading the action isn't in the spirit of the mechanics here.

However, the logical downgrade would be to a move action, this would provide you with some value because to get your shield back would then require a minor action to pick it up and standard to equip it.